# Stored Procedure (Exec) in Datazen

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, datazen-server

I've been trying to use a Stored Procedure in Datazen, but every time I build the dataset, it doesnt actually return any data (yet doesnt give me an error and does give me the column headings). I've tried the same query in SSRS 2016 and the new mobile report builder, and both work a charm, but Datazens just not having it.

```
USE [SSRS_Reports_SPs]
EXEC [dbo].[Test]
```

Really, I just want to know if its possible in datazen, and if so what I might be doing wrong.
Cheers

Comment: Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the beginning of your SP? There was such problem with some PHP code, all was working without errors, but when fetching SP results - there was nothing, this option helps.

Comment: No it doesnt start with SET NOCOUNT ON, shame that sounded like a simple solution

Comment: So it works now? Or this was not helpful?

Comment: No its not working now I'm afraid

Comment: Stored Procs certainly work in DataZen but if you're in SSRS 2016, the previous version of DataZen has now become the Mobile Report Publisher. What do you mean by DataZen?